# redirecting php.ini's blank error page

Tags: php, error-handling, content-management-system, http-status-code-404

A site that I built using a particular CMS (not Wordpress) works well, but if someone who knows the CMS were to type (this is an illustration, not an actual URL) http://example.com/blog/cms/connect.php (he would know the path if he was familiar with the CMS) an error would be returned, displaying the full path of the file. I used `display_errors = Off` in php.ini to prevent this. However, this results in a blank page; what could I do to make it result in an error 404 page instead? (I know HOW to make a PHP page return a 404 status code, which is how content files like header.php and footer.php return a 404 if someone types those URLs directly into the browser.)

Comment: If you're using a class and/or methods, "return" the method rather than echoing, should this be the case. You could also store them outside the public area and include/require.

Comment: *"However, this results in a blank page; what could I do to make it result in an error 404 page instead?"* - Use `.htaccess` ErrorDocument.